# Switching Dictionary Keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 Dictionaries, they both contain the same keys (or they would with a little cutting, `[3:]`) but different values. I would like to replace the keys in one dictionary with the values of another. For example here is a portion of my lists:

Dict 1

```
 "AED":"United Arab Emirates Dirham",
 "AFN":"Afghan Afghani",
 "ALL":"Albanian Lek",
 "AMD":"Armenian Dram",
 "ANG":"Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
 "AOA":"Angolan Kwanza",
 "ARS":"Argentine Peso"
```

Dict2

```
 "USDAED":3.672301,
 "USDAFN":66.800003,
 "USDALL":127.000221,
 "USDAMD":486.160004,
 "USDANG":1.769942,
 "USDAOA":165.080994,
 "USDARS":15.609965
```

I would like a list with the first entry reading
 "United Arab Emirates Dirham":3.672301
Any thoughts? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: The keys don't look the same...?

Comment: As I said, they would have to be cut [3:] but that's fairly simple.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do that with a one-liner (dict comprehension)

```
dict1={"AED":"United Arab Emirates Dirham",
 "AFN":"Afghan Afghani",
 "ALL":"Albanian Lek",
 "AMD":"Armenian Dram",
 "ANG":"Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
 "AOA":"Angolan Kwanza",
 "ARS":"Argentine Peso"}

dict2 = {"USDAED":3.672301,
 "USDAFN":66.800003,
 "USDALL":127.000221,
 "USDAMD":486.160004,
 "USDANG":1.769942,
 "USDAOA":165.080994,
 "USDARS":15.609965}

dict3 = {dict1[x[3:]]:y for x,y in dict2.items()}

print(dict3)
```

yields:

```
{'Albanian Lek': 127.000221, 'Netherlands Antillean Guilder': 1.769942,
 'Armenian Dram': 486.160004, 'United Arab Emirates Dirham': 3.672301, 
'Afghan Afghani': 66.800003, 'Argentine Peso': 15.609965,
'Angolan Kwanza': 165.080994}
```

The code recreates a third dictionary with as key: values of the first one (with the small key cutoff you mentionned, and as values: values of the second one

Note: as dicts are not ordered your "first entry" wish doesn't hold, unless you print the items sorted of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict2 = {dict1[key[3:]], value for key, value in dict2.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

To change/update the first dictionary use [**dict.update()**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) function:

```
# d1 and d2 are the first and the second dicts respectively
d1.update({k[3:]:v for k,v in d2.items()})
print(d1)
```

The output:

```
{'AFN': 66.800003, 'AOA': 165.080994, 'AED': 3.672301, 'ALL': 127.000221, 'ARS': 15.609965, 'AMD': 486.160004, 'ANG': 1.769942}
```